# Google token auth with Express and Passport not working

Tags: express, passport.js, google-oauth

I've made a REST api with Express which uses Passport and the `passport-google-token` strategy to authenticate users. It works as expected when my server is running on localhost but it doesn't work on the live version of the server. All calls return a 401 Unauthorized response.

The passport strategy is configured like this:

```
this.passport.use(new GoogleTokenStrategy({
  clientID: this.config.auth.googleAuth.clientId,
  clientSecret: this.config.auth.googleAuth.clientSecret
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  User.findOne({'google.id': profile.id}, (err, user) => {
    if(err) return done(err);
    if(user) return done(null, user);

    var newUser = new User();

    newUser.save((err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      return done(null, newUser);
    });
  })
}));
```

And here's an example of an endpoint. It returns a 401 response when I hit it with a valid Google access token, but only on the live domain - it works on localhost.

```
app.get("/api/exists", passport.authenticate("google-token"), (req, res) => {
  // stuff happens here
});
```

Here's what my credentials look like in the Google API manager:
[image: Google API credentials]

If it's relevant, the client in this case is a Chrome extension which gets tokens using [getAuthToken](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity). The code that does the requests from the client looks like this:

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({"interactive": true}, (token) => {
  const bodyJson = body ? JSON.stringify(body) : null;
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Access_token", token);
  headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  const request = new Request(url, {
    headers: headers,
    method: method,
    body: bodyJson
  });

  fetch(request);
});
```

But even if I generate a token from [the Google oauth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and make the request via Postman, I get the same result: it works on localhost and doesn't work on the real domain.

What else do I need to do to authenticate users on my live domain?

Comment: Did you try adding the path to the "Authorized redirect URIs" section? If the Node server is doing the authentication you need to configure that since it's doing the authentication, not the browser.

Comment: The client in this case is a Chrome extension so it can't perform redirects. The token comes from the logged in user, using [getAuthToken](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity) so it's Google doing the authentication

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue turned out to be with my Nginx server. By default it strips out headers that contain an underscore (e.g. `access_token`). It didn't occur to me that the problem would be there, hence not even mentioning it in my question.

[Docs about that are here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers). You can change the behaviour by setting:

```
underscores_in_headers on
```